# Pressing <Enter> after editing the title hangs the post editor

Tags: bug, questions, edits

When changing the question title and then pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> immediately after, the submit button is greyed out and the editor either hangs or responds with long delay. This does not happen when pressing the button with a mouse.

I can't narrow down the exact circumstances, so I am not sure if other people can reproduce the same issue.

It never happened to me on Meta yet, but it does happen on main occasionally.

OS: Windows 10 21H1
Browser: Google Chrome 91

Comment: P.S. It's also possible there is a generic performance issue, but I only observed it when editing titles so far.

Comment: You are editing an existing post right? Not creating a new question?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Chrome / Windows, when I edit the title of this question.

Comment: I am editing an existing question. Maybe it only happens on main?

Comment: something is hanging indeed. I repro-ed partially.

Comment: @rene Why does the revision history show I remove a word, but the word is still there?

Comment: That is weird indeed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pagDB.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kkq7.png

Comment: No repro in Chrome on Windows, either. Please [edit] the question to include browser, OS, phase of the moon, pet's name, and any other relevant info.

Comment: Was it starlings or mockingbirds circling overhead, and were they going clockwise or counter-clockwise?